# Strange behaviour of sqlite finalize statement. High Chances of App Rejection in Appstore review Process

Tags: iphone, database, xcode, sqlite

Today I have faced very strange behavior of `sqlite3_finalize` statement.

I am using sqlite since last 2 years and didn't faced such problem before.

Issue is:

My whole app is working fine when my xcode Active configuration is in debug mode. 
As soon as I switched Active Configuration from Debug to Release, my app starts crashing at `sqlite3_finalize` statement in my Database Manager class.

Anyone can suggest some possible solution ? I have given Appstore release as well and I am pretty sure app will be rejected because appstore build will always be in Release Configuration mode and it will crash in Review period.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was calling another sql operation on insertion failure... so i fixed the issue by closing previous sql operation

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you use amalgamation code from sqlite.org and configured it only for "*Debug*" build? What king of error you get? Debugger should said something about crash.